# How to add photos into UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have creates a UICollectionView which I currently have showing white cells. I have been following this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) to figure out how to use the delegate methods etc.

I have made it up to the point where you create the **Creating custom UICollectionViewCells** however in this example the tutorial he tells you to open your story board etc. I don't have a story board. I have tried to follow the instructions to create the view but with my own .xib file and I just cannot get anything to work.

How can I check out where my delegate methods are at this point?

```
// this is how I load the collection view
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    photoCollectionView =[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 40.0, 480.0, 713.0) collectionViewLayout:layout];

    photoCollectionView.dataSource = self;
    photoCollectionView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:photoCollectionView];

    [photoCollectionView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
    [photoCollectionView.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    [self.photoCollectionView reloadData];



// this is what my delegate methods look like
#pragma mark - CollectionView Delegates
#pragma mark -- UICollectionView Datasource
// 1
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [imageArray count];
}
// 2
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}
// 3
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // I think this is where I want to set my image for the cell
    NSDictionary *currentPhotoDict = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *imageForCollection = [UIImage imageWithData:[currentPhotoDict objectForKey:@"DImage"]];

    // but I have no idea where to pass the imag....

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return cell;
}


#pragma mark -- UICollectionView Delegate
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // TODO: Select Item
}
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // TODO: Deselect item
}


#pragma mark –- UICollectionViewDelegate FlowLayout

// 1
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   
    CGSize retval = CGSizeMake(210, 157+20); // add 20 for labels under neath.. might need to adjust this.
    return retval;
}


- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 20, 50, 20);


}Subview:photoCollectionView];

        [photoCollectionView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
        [photoCollectionView.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
        [self.photoCollectionView reloadData];
```

As you can see in **collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath** I have my image ready

```
NSDictionary *currentPhotoDict = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UIImage *imageForCollection = [UIImage imageWithData:[currentPhotoDict objectForKey:@"DImage"]];
```

I just need to know how to load it into the collectionviewcell.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use like this....

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // I think this is where I want to set my image for the cell
    NSDictionary *currentPhotoDict = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *imageForCollection = [UIImage imageWithData:[currentPhotoDict objectForKey:@"DImage"]];
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:imageForCollection];// Add your image here........

    // but I have no idea where to pass the imag....

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return cell;
}
```

i hope it will help you...

Comment: The code is now producing an error ***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier PhotoCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'**

Comment: Where you are allocating memory to your cell ?

Answer (score 0):

I have UICollectionViewCell with name PhotoCell. and have label and imageview as properties.
This is how u can set Image to cell. May this is your requirement or not. I dont know. Try this

You need to set identifier at Xib of your UICollectionViewCell as MY_CELL or some other name.Then

.m

```
 static NSString *cellidentity=@"MY_CELL";
```

At ViewDidLoad method

```
UINib *nib;
nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PhotoCell" bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellidentity];
```

My UICollectionViewCell .h is

```
@interface PhotoCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel* label;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel* timelineLabel;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* yourImageView;

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
   // PhotoCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell" //forIndexPath:indexPath];
PhotoCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellidentity forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *currentPhotoDict = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *imageForCollection = [UIImage imageWithData:[currentPhotoDict objectForKey:@"DImage"]];

    // but I have no idea where to pass the imag....

    cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.item];

    cell.yourImageView.image=imageForCollection;

    return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps You....

Comment: okay I have figured out how to do what you have asked I am getting this as an error though. **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'**